# Need driver for Alps touchpad on a Vaio F2 VPCF2190X that supports Multi-touch

Tags: 11.10, drivers, touchpad, multi-touch, trackpad

I have a Sony Vaio VPCF2190X with an Alps Multi-touch trackpad, and I can't use multi-touch. Is there a resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be filed as a bug. [Here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) is a link to a document with information regarding troubleshooting Touchpad problems, and it has information on how to file a bug report.